# what to do after creating mongodb atlas cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have created a mongodb free tier atlas cluster. I added an user in *Database Acess -> Database Users*.

But I don't know if there is anything else to set up, any other kind of users inside the cluster.
Can someone help me with the extra steps (that mongodb "doesnt tell" you to do)?

Comment: Did you follow along with the [Getting Started](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/)?

Comment: if I understand it right, the admin users needs to be created when I want to use mongodb locally